# Flutter :- How to scroll the sceen without shrink the screen on the Stack view?(Scroll the the whole screen when the keyboard appears )

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**Description**
 I am creating the login screen in which I have used the `Stack` widget, Currently, everything works fine but only one issue of the shrinking the view. When I use the  **`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false`** inside the `Scaffold` then screen shrinking disappear but another problem arise that whole screen scroll not working, please check below lines of code

```
 class _LoginScreen extends State<LoginScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build

        return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            body:  Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 9,
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: RotatedBox(
                                    quarterTurns: 3,
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Login !!",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 30.0,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 6,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Image(
                        image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
                        color: null,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                        ],
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Please enter mobile number")),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        obscureText: true,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(16),
                        ],
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Password")),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 3.0,
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child: Text(
                          "Forgot Password?",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                        )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 3.0,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black45),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ));
      }
    }
```

From Above code, I am getting the following screen

[image]
   
    I have used the `ListView` and `SingleChildScrollView` but it not working properly, please check my code with `SingleChildScrollView`, which i have tried

```
class _LoginScreen extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 4,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 9,
                              child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: RotatedBox(
                                      quarterTurns: 3,
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Login !!",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 30.0,
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 6,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Image(
                      image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
                      color: null,
                      height: 100.0,
                      width: 100.0,
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                        ],
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
                            ),
                            hintText: "Please enter mobile number")),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                        obscureText: true,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(16),
                        ],
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
                            ),
                            hintText: "Password")),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 3.0,
                    ),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child: Text(
                          "Forgot Password?",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                        )),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 3.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: const Text(
                        'Login',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black45),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ));
  }
}
```

And From the above code getting this result by using the `SingleChildScrollView`

[image]

**Problem**:- **I want to scroll the whole screen when the keyboard appears**, I have used all the `Listview` and `SingleChildScrollView` but not getting the solution, please help me on it. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by scrolling ! There is no scope for scrolling because your widgets are not more than your screen ! Do want to scroll even without more children ?

Comment: @NaveenAvidi I want to scroll the widget when **keyboard** appears

Comment: wrap the Column widget with Flexible !

Comment: Hi @NaveenAvidi , I want to scroll the screen when the keyboard appears. The wrap is not applicable there, please check my code once.

Comment: Why are you using resizetoPad...... ?

Comment: Where i have used it **resizetoPad** ? Sorry do not get your point

Comment: I mean this one resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,

Comment: @NaveenAvidi I have mentioned that i have used the `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` , please check my question once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using Expanded widgets, you see expanded widgets are flexible in nature they will consume and shrink according to the available space. If you don't want that you need to specify a height.

https://i.imgur.com/wVgAUlN.mp4

```
class StacScroll extends StatefulWidget {
  StacScroll({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StacScrollState createState() => _StacScrollState();
}

class _StacScrollState extends State<StacScroll> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          // margin:
          //     EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: RotatedBox(
                      quarterTurns: 3,
                      child: Container(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            "Login !!",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Image(
                          image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
                          color: null,
                          height: 100.0,
                          width: 100.0,
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
                                ),
                                hintText: "Please enter mobile number")),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                            obscureText: true,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
                                ),
                                hintText: "Password")),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 3.0,
                        ),
                        Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: Text(
                              "Forgot Password?",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 3.0,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: const Text(
                            'Login',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black45),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Means ,  I need to remove the Expand widget and use the MediQuery to specify the height of the widget

Comment: Can  you please elobrate the **0.3** multiple logic in mediaquery

Comment: Yes if you do want them to shrink dynamically. The 0.3 means it's 30% of device height. Use should always try using percentages in stack because different devices meaning unintentional miss alignments.

Comment: Means for the  full view i need to use **1** and half view i need to use the **5**

Comment: But you have used the **0.3** in both the view and it is working fine

Comment: It's an expression for calcutlating a percentage 0.3 is nothing but 30/100 similar 70% of device height/width will be ( height * 70/100) => (hieght * 0.7). So 100% will be 1.

Comment: The first container has a height of 30% and the second container has a MARGIN of 30% from the top, which basically means leave 30% height from above and then draw the widget.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your input, glad to give you bounty points.Please up-vote my question also

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nadeem by which problem has resolved
Whenever we want to scroll the full screen when keyboard appear then we should **not** use the `Expand` widget for it.I was also doing the same mistake, for the other user i have modified the code for full scroll when keyboard appear, I have used the `MediaQuery` for it,Please check my below code of it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _LoginScreen();
  }
}

class _LoginScreen extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
              ),
              Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.59,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3),
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Enter your username')),
                        TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password')),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          child: Text("Submit",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
              Center(
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  elevation: 8,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .25),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      "Radhe",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20.0),
                    )),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .1,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .3,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please check the output of it.
[image]