# How to show a widget over the keyboard in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, flutter-widget

I want to place a widget on top of everything (a loading widget), but I can not manage to place it over the keyboard too.

I've tried some methods, but the widget is always under the keyboard. Is there any way to place it over it?

**Example using all kind of Stacks**

Using stacks, I can not position the loading over the keyboard.

What I want:

[image]

What I super sadly get:

[image]

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61101042/3946958

Comment: I need the widget to be placed over the keyboard (overlap it), not on top of it.

Comment: Please add some code along with question like what have you tried for it

Comment: I've added some pictures of what I really want.

Comment: It will be blocked only while the loading process is being done (less than a second). Why blocking the UI should be a silly idea? Using this concept, the user will not to touch the screen until the process end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but I can't write comments yet.

You won't be able to do that with Flutter (I think) as the keyboard is handled by the **Android System** itself.

Anyway, Blocking the **phone's UI** is not something that should be even tried in most circumstances.
Blocking just your **app's UI** though, is the right approach whenever you have some processo to wait for.

Be careful when designing your ideas. The user is free to use his/her other resources as he or she sees fit and you shouldn't try to control what your user does outside of your application.